# Create an Hashtag system using Node JS and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I want to create an app where users have the ability to assign tags to their content using Node and MongoDB.

So far, I have been able to insert the tags into the database as an array.

This is how it looks like:

```
 "tags": [
        "laughing",
        "smile"
    ]
```

Now I have a problem when it comes to displaying the tags on the frontend using the ejs template.

When I run the following the code:

```
   <% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { %>

<%= tags[i] %>

<%}%>
```

The result is the following:

```
laughing, smiling
```

Yes it does give me the right answer but what I really wanted is a way to wrap each entity around `<a></a>`. something like `<a href=''> laughing </a> <a href="">smiling</a>`

I want to make this possible but I have not seen a way to achieve this using ejs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply try:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) { %>
   <a href=""><%= tags[i] %></a>
<%}%>
```

Never used ejs but it look like all others templates languages syntax.

Comment: Yes. But it's giving me the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
<%var data = { "tags" : ["laughing", "smile"] };
var tagsArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
  tagsArr.push(data.tags[i].split(","));
}%>
```

Then use tagsArr -

```
<% for(let i=0; i<tagsArr.length; i++) { %>
   <a href=""><%= tagsArr[i] %></a>
<%}%>
```

Comment: The first example you gave is not in EJS.

Comment: I'm getting `tags.split is not a function` as the error message.

Comment: i have edited the code, plz try now (add the first part in script and second part in ejs)

Comment: You know the `tags` is coming from the DB. so it has to be rendered by EJS, not inside the script.

Comment: then put both part in ejs